# Assign help() to a variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to assign a `help()` page to a variable as a string; for example

```
a = help("class")
print a
```

Is this possible and how would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can retrive the documentation directly.

```
from pydoc_data import topics

a = topics.topics['class']
print a
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import pydoc

a = pydoc.render_doc('class')
print a
```

Comment: This dont seem to work... Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/Storage/Workspace/tmp/justsome.py", line 3, in <module>
    a = pydoc.render_doc('class')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pydoc.py", line 1507, in render_doc
    object, name = resolve(thing, forceload)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pydoc.py", line 1499, in resolve
    raise ImportError, 'no Python documentation found for %r' % thing
ImportError: no Python documentation found for 'class'

Comment: Sorry, I took 'class' to mean a generic place holder.  Not the actual help() topic 'class'.  It does work for actual classes.  Try it with 'pprint' or 'set'.